# Beginner Script using switch structure isn't running

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

so this is the script I am trying to run:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml;
charset=utf-8" />
<title>rollDie.html</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// DiceRomanNumbers
var die = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
var output = "";
switch(die){
case 1:
    output = "I";
    break;
case 2:
    output = "II";
    break;
case 3:
    output = "III";
    break;
case 4:
    output = "IV";
    break;
case 5:
    output = "V";
    break;
case 6:
    output = "VI";
    break;
default:
    output = "PROBLEM!!!";
} // end switch
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

However, when I run it, nothing shows up. What should appear is a dialogue box with a Roman Numeral 1-6. Can anyone point out the mistake? I've been stressing over why it won't run for an hour now.

Comment: I think you missed the code?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to show the code, I miss-indented the coding.

canon, thank you, that was what I was missing!

Comment: If @canon answered your question, make sure to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Shows up where? You didn't do anything with `output` after setting it. Add the following after your switch:

```
alert(output);
```

[**edit**]: [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmqVb/)

Answer (score 0):

Your output is never displayed because you don't have any code that displays it. For a simple test, add `alert(output);`.

Also note that most javascript switch statements could be better written using object literals:

```
var numerals = {
    '1': 'I',
    '2': 'II',
    '3': 'III',
    '4': 'IV',
    '5': 'V',
    '6': 'VI'
};

alert(numerals[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)]);
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9qda/).

Comment: It might be worth amending that to say _"javascript switch statements **used as dictionaries** could be better written using object literals."_